# "pynvml.NVMLError_LibraryNotFound: NVML Shared Library Not Found" in bitbucket-pipelines

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to execute the following `bitbucket-pipelines` config:

```
clone:
  depth: full

options:
    max-time: 4 # maximum minutes to run the tests

pipelines:
    pull-requests:  # run when pull request is created (or updated)
        "**":  # this runs as default for any branch not elsewhere defined
            - step:
                name: Tests  # name to show on the pipelines web page
                image: python:3.7  # docker to use (from Docker Hub)
                script:  # shell commands to run
                    - pip install -r requirements.txt
                    - python -m pytest --junitxml=./test-reports/junit.xml .
```

However, when the `unitests` are executed i get the following errors (in bitbucket-pipeline):

```
pynvml.NVMLError_LibraryNotFound: NVML Shared Library Not Found
def _LoadNvmlLibrary():
        '''
        Load the library if it isn't loaded already
        '''
        global nvmlLib
    
        if (nvmlLib == None):
            # lock to ensure only one caller loads the library
            libLoadLock.acquire()
    
            try:
                # ensure the library still isn't loaded
                if (nvmlLib == None):
                    try:
                        if (sys.platform[:3] == "win"):
                            # cdecl calling convention
                            # load nvml.dll from %ProgramFiles%/NVIDIA Corporation/NVSMI/nvml.dll
                            nvmlLib = CDLL(os.path.join(os.getenv("ProgramFiles", "C:/Program Files"), "NVIDIA Corporation/NVSMI/nvml.dll"))
                        else:
                            # assume linux
>                           nvmlLib = CDLL("libnvidia-ml.so.1")
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pynvml.py:644: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
self = <CDLL 'libnvidia-ml.so.1', handle 0 at 0x7fcc75c8a910>
name = 'libnvidia-ml.so.1', mode = 0, handle = None, use_errno = False
use_last_error = False
    def __init__(self, name, mode=DEFAULT_MODE, handle=None,
                 use_errno=False,
                 use_last_error=False):
        self._name = name
        flags = self._func_flags_
        if use_errno:
            flags |= _FUNCFLAG_USE_ERRNO
        if use_last_error:
            flags |= _FUNCFLAG_USE_LASTERROR
        if _sys.platform.startswith("aix"):
            """When the name contains ".a(" and ends with ")",
               e.g., "libFOO.a(libFOO.so)" - this is taken to be an
               archive(member) syntax for dlopen(), and the mode is adjusted.
               Otherwise, name is presented to dlopen() as a file argument.
            """
            if name and name.endswith(")") and ".a(" in name:
                mode |= ( _os.RTLD_MEMBER | _os.RTLD_NOW )
    
        class _FuncPt
```

After reading issues, it seems that it related to NVidia drivers. However, i'm not sure if it is the case. In if it is the case, how can i fix these issues.